# Can't initialize a geofire object in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic2, geofire

I'm working with the `ionic-framework version 2` and `typescript`.

Last week I integrated **Firebase** in my app, which worked fine. Now I want to integrate **geofire** too, but I can't initialize an instance of a geofire object.

My **MainSearchPage class:**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import { GeoFire } from 'geofire';

constructor(public af: AngularFire, @Inject(FirebaseApp) firebaseApp: firebase.app.App) {
    var firebaseRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();
    var geofire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
}
```

But I always get the following error:

> Error in ./MainSearchPage class MainSearchPage_Host - caused by: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_geofire**.GeoFire is not a constructor

**Versions:**

```
ionic-app-script 1.3.1,
typescript 2.0.6,
firebase 3.7.5,
angularfire 2.0.0-beta.8,
geofire 4.1.2,
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: did you found a solution for this? i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try importing Geofire like this

`import * as GeoFire from "geofire";`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!! Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)